# Regex with possible empty matches and multi-line match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I've been trying to *"parse"* some data using a regex, and I feel as if I'm close, but I just can't seem to bring it all home.
The data that needs parsing generally looks like this: `<param>: <value>\n`. The number of params can vary, just as the value can. Still, here's an example:

```
FooID: 123456
Name: Chuck
When: 01/02/2013 01:23:45
InternalID: 789654
User Message: Hello,
this is nillable, but can be quite long. Text can be spread out over many lines
And can start with any number of \n's. It can be empty, too.
What's worse, though is that this CAN contain colons (but they're _"escaped"_ using `\`), and even basic markup!
```

To push this text into an object, I put together this little expresion

```
if (preg_match_all('/^([^:\n\\]+):\s*(.+)/m', $this->structuredMessage, $data))
{
    $data = array_combine($data[1], $data[2]);
    //$data is assoc array FooID => 123456, Name => Chuck, ...
    $report = new Report($data);
}
```

Now, this works allright most of the time, except for the `User Message` bit: `.` doesn't match new lines, because if I were to use the `s` flag, the second group would match everything after `FooID:` till the very end of the string.
I'm having to use a dirty workaround for that:

```
$msg = explode(end($data[1], $string);
$data[2][count($data[2])-1] = array_pop($msg);
```

After some testing, I've come to understand that sometimes, one or two of the parameters aren't filled in (for example the `InternalID` can be empty). In that case, my expression doesn't fail, but rather results in:

```
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => FooID
            [1] => Name
            [2] => When
            [3] => InternalID
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123465
            [1] => Chuck
            [2] => 01/02/2013 01:23:45
            [3] => User Comment: Hello,
        )
```

I've been trying various other expressions, and came up with this:

```
/^([^:\n\\]++)\s{0,}:(.*+)(?!^[^:\n\\]++\s{0,}:)/m
//or:
/^([^:\n\\]+)\s{0,}:(.*)(?!^[^:\\\n]+\s{0,}:)/m
```

The second version being slightly slower. 
That solves the issues I had with `InternalID: <void>`, but still leaves me with the final obstacle: `User Message: <multi-line>`. Using the `s` flag doesn't do the trick with my expression ATM. 
I can only think of this:

```
^([^:\n\\]++)\s{0,}:((\n(?![^\n:\\]++\s{0,}:)|.)*+)
```

Which is, to my eye at least, too complex to be the only option. Ideas, suggestions, links, ... anything would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If the content may contain colons as well, what criteria could we use to identify those in order not to confuse them with a key/value separating colon?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Good point, I've checked. The text is generated by another program, which actually escapes colons in the user input. I've updated my expressions, both here and in my code :)

Comment: Oh, if colons are escaped, then it's easy. Hang on a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should work, but I'm not so sure anymore if it is the right tool for this:

```
preg_match_all(
    '%^            # Start of line
    ([^:]*)        # Match anything until a colon, capture in group 1
    :\s*           # Match a colon plus optional whitespace
    (              # Match and capture in group 2:
     (?:           # Start of non-capturing group (used for alternation)
      .*$          #  Either match the rest of the line
      (?=          #  only if one of the following follows here:
       \Z          #  The end of the string
      |            #  or
       \r?\n       #  a newline
       [^:\n\\\\]* #  followed by anything except colon, backslash or newline
       :           #  then a colon
      )            #  End of lookahead
     |             # or match
      (?:          #  Start of non-capturing group (used for alternation/repetition)
       [^:\\\\]    #  Either match a character except colon or backslash
      |            #  or
       \\\\.       #  match any escaped character
      )*           #  Repeat as needed (end of inner non-capturing group)
     )             # End of outer non-capturing group
    )              # End of capturing group 2
    $              # Match the end of the line%mx', 
    $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

See it [live on regex101](http://regex101.com/r/sC1yC4).

Comment: Thanks, though (I'm sorry for being picky) only the colons in the user input are escaped. The other values are guaranteed to be in-line (single line matches), but a date `j/m/Y H:i:s` is often supplied

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: I worked this into the regex. It should be OK again, but it's become quite unwieldy. I'm pretty sure I'd be having a hard time debugging this six months from now...

Answer (score 1):

i'm pretty new to PHP so maybe this is totally out of whack, but maybe you could use something like

```
$data = <<<EOT
FooID: 123456
Name: Chuck
When: 01/02/2013 01:23:45
InternalID: 789654
User Message: Hello,
this is nillable, but can be quite long. Text can be spread out over many     lines
And can start with any number of \n's. It can be empty, too
EOT;

if ($key = preg_match_all('~^[^:\n]+?:~m', $data, $match)) {
    $val = explode('¬', preg_filter('~^[^:\n]+?:~m', '¬', $data));

    array_shift($val);

    $res = array_combine($match[0], $val);
}

print_r($res);
```

yields

```
Array
(
    [FooID:] =>  123456
    [Name:] =>  Chuck
    [When:] =>  01/02/2013 01:23:45
    [InternalID:] =>  789654
    [User Message:] =>  Hello,
this is nillable, but can be quite long. Text can be spread out over many     lines
And can start with any number of 
's. It can be empty, too
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, `~^[^:\n]+?~m` would be better, IMO (not including the colon in the match, but this still requires 2 regex's, and doesn't deal with escaped colons

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd avoid using regex to do this task, instead split it into sub-tasks.

#### Basic algorithm outline

1. Split the string on `\n` using `explode`
2. Loop over the resulting array

   1. Split the resulting strings on `:` also using `explode` with a limit of 2.
   2. If the produced array's length is less than 2, add the entirety of the data to the previous key's value
   3. Else, use the first array index as your key, the second as the value *unless* the split colon was escaped (in which case, instead add the key + split + value to the previous key's value)

This algorithm does assume there are no *keys* with escaped colons. Escaped colons in values will be dealt with just fine (i.e. user input).

#### Code

```
$str = <<<EOT
FooID: 123456
Name: Chuck
When: 01/02/2013 01:23:45
InternalID: 
User Message: Hello,
this is nillable, but can be quite long. Text can be spread out over many lines
This\: works too. And can start with any number of \\n's. It can be empty, too.
What's worse, though is that this CAN contain colons (but they're _"escaped"_


using `\`) like so `\:`, and even basic markup!
EOT;

$arr = explode("\n", $str);

$prevKey = '';
$split = ': ';
$output = array();
for ($i = 0, $arrlen = sizeof($arr); $i < $arrlen; $i++) {
  $keyValuePair = explode($split, $arr[$i], 2);
  // ?: Is this a valid key/value pair
  if (sizeof($keyValuePair) < 2 && $i > 0) {
    // -> Nope, append the value to the previous key's value
    $output[$prevKey] .= "\n" . $keyValuePair[0];
  }
  else {
    // -> Maybe
    // ?: Did we miss an escaped colon
    if (substr($keyValuePair[0], -1) === '\\') {
      // -> Yep, this means this is a value, not a key/value pair append both key and
      // value (including the split between) to the previous key's value ignoring
      // any colons in the rest of the string (allowing dates to pass through)
      $output[$prevKey] .= "\n" . $keyValuePair[0] . $split . $keyValuePair[1];
    }
    else {
      // -> Nope, create a new key with a value
      $output[$keyValuePair[0]] = $keyValuePair[1];
      $prevKey = $keyValuePair[0];
    }
  }
}

var_dump($output);
```

#### Output

```
array(5) {
  ["FooID"]=>
  string(6) "123456"
  ["Name"]=>
  string(5) "Chuck"
  ["When"]=>
  string(19) "01/02/2013 01:23:45"
  ["InternalID"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["User Message"]=>
  string(293) "Hello,
this is nillable, but can be quite long. Text can be spread out over many lines
This\: works too. And can start with any number of \n's. It can be empty, too.
What's worse, though is that this CAN contain colons (but they're _"escaped"_


using `\`) like so `\:`, and even basic markup!"
}
```

**[Online demo](http://ideone.com/eUqI3s)**

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention that the values always contain colons (the date format ends with `H:i:s`), and the User Message almost always contains `\n`, and can contain colons, too

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Given that colons are escaped, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I came up with using a tricky [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback):

```
$string ='FooID: 123456
Name: Chuck
When: 01/02/2013 01:23:45
InternalID: 789654
User Message: Hello,
this is nillable, but can be quite long. Text can be spread out over many lines
And can start with any number of \n\'s. It can be empty, too
Yellow:cool';

$array = array();
preg_replace_callback('#^(.*?):(.*)|.*$#m', function($m)use(&$array){
    static $last_key = ''; // We are going to use this as a reference
    if(isset($m[1])){// If there is a normal match (key : value)
        $array[$m[1]] = $m[2]; // Then add to array
        $last_key = $m[1]; // define the new last key
    }else{ // else
        $array[$last_key] .= PHP_EOL . $m[0]; // add the whole line to the last entry
    }
}, $string); // Anonymous function used thus PHP 5.3+ is required
print_r($array); // print
```

[**Online demo**](http://ideone.com/vwEXfi)

**Downside**: I'm using `PHP_EOL` to add newlines which is OS related.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I forgot to mention that the user message can contain colons, too. [which messes up your code](http://ideone.com/O2H1t9). Also: I'm not keen on using closures in PHP