# wrap words in string with regex

Tags: php, regex-negation

**This is the string** 

(code)

```
Pivot: 96.75<br />Our preference: Long positions above 96.75 with targets @ 97.8 &amp; 98.25 in extension.<br />Alternative scenario: Below 96.75 look for further downside with 96.35 &amp; 95.9 as targets.<br />Comment the pair has broken above its resistance and should post further advance.<br />
```

(text)

"Pivot: 96.75
Our preference: Long positions above 96.75 with targets @ 97.8 & 98.25 in extension.
Alternative scenario: Below 96.75 look for further downside with 96.35 & 95.9 as targets.
Comment the pair has broken above its resistance and should post further advance.
"

**the result should be** 

(code)

```
<b>Pivot</b>: 96.75<br /><b>Our preference</b>: Long positions above 96.75 with targets @ 97.8 &amp; 98.25 in extension.<br /><b>Alternative scenario</b>: Below 96.75 look for further downside with 96.35 &amp; 95.9 as targets.<br />Comment the pair has broken above its resistance and should post further advance.<br />
```

(text)
**Pivot**: 96.75
**Our preference**: Long positions above 96.75 with targets @ 97.8 & 98.25 in extension.
**Alternative scenario**: Below 96.75 look for further downside with 96.35 & 95.9 as targets.
Comment the pair has broken above its resistance and should post further advance.

**The porpuse**:
Wrap all the words before `:` sign.

I've tried this regex: `((\A )|(<br />))(?P<G>[^:]*):`, but its working only on python environment. I need this in PHP:

```
$pattern = '/((\A)|(<br\s\/>))(?P<G>[^:]*):/';
$description = preg_replace($pattern, '<b>$1</b>', $description);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should start by saying that HTML operations are better done with a proper parser such as `DOMDocument`. This particular problem is straightforward, so regular expressions may work without too much hocus pocus, but be warned :)

You can use look-around [assertions](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php); this frees you from having to restore the neighbouring strings during the replacement:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?<=^|<br \/>)[^:]+(?=:)/m', '<b>$0</b>', $str);
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4Br7pf)

First, the look-behind assertion matches either the start of each line or a preceding `<br />`. Then, any characters except the colon are matched; the look-ahead assertion makes sure it's followed by a colon.

The `/m` modifier is used to make `^` match the start of each line as opposed to `\A` which always matches the start of the subject string.

Answer (score 2):

This preg_replace should do the trick:

```
preg_replace('#(^|<br ?/>)([^:]+):#m','$1<b>$2</b>:',$input)
```

[PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2d0-ba6) - Run (F9)

Answer (score 1):

The most *"general"* and least regex-expensive way to do this that I could come up with was this:

```
$parts = explode('<br', $str);//don't include space and `/`, as tags may vary
$formatted = '';
foreach($parts as $part)
{
    $formatted .= preg_replace('/^\s*[\/>]{0,2}\s*([^:]+:)/', '<b>$1</b>',$part).'<br/>';
}
echo $formatted;
```

Or:

```
$formatted = array();
foreach($parts as $part)
{
    $formatted[] = preg_replace('/^\s*[\/>]{0,2}\s*([^:]+:)/', '<b>$1</b>',$part);
}
echo implode('<br/>', $formatted);
```

Tested with, and gotten this as output

**Pivot:** 96.75
**Our preference:** Long positions above 96.75 with targets @ 97.8 & 98.25 in extension.
**Alternative scenario:** Below 96.75 look for further downside with 96.35 & 95.9 as targets.
Comment the pair has broken above its resistance and should post further advance.

That being said, I do find this bit of data *weird*, and, if I were you, I'd consider `str_replace` or `preg_replace`-ing all breaks with `PHP_EOL`:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\<\s*br\s*\/?\s*\>/i', PHP_EOL, $str);//allow for any form of break tag
```

And then, your string looks *exactly* like [the data I had to parse, and got the regex for that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570544/regex-with-possible-empty-matches-and-multi-line-match):

```
$str = preg_replace(...);
$formatted = preg_replace('/^([^:\n\\]++)\s{0,}:((\n(?![^\n:\\]++\s{0,}:)|.)*+)/','<b>$1:</b>$2<br/>', $str);
```